# How can I show Scheduled Scaling configuration on web Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

How can I show AWS EC2 Auto Scaling's Scheduled Scaling configuration on web Console?

As the [Official Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/schedule_time.html) says, with aws-cli, the size of Auto Scaling Group can be changed based on time like the following:

```
$ aws autoscaling put-scheduled-update-group-action --scheduled-action-name my-schedule --auto-scaling-group-name my-group --recurrence '0 0 * * *' --desired-capacity 1
```

.

However, I can't find a way to show this configuration on web Console.  Is this information only available through aws-cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news... this feature has just been added!

See: [Create a Scheduled Action Using the Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/schedule_time.html#create-sch-actions)

[image: Scheduling Auto Scaling from the console]